# How to split the numeric values string split into digits in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
ID  PHONE
1   9701245929
2   66663333
3   9701245931
4   9701245932
5   26668888
6   48228899
7   88229933
```

OUTPUT:

```
ID  PHONE
1   9701 245 929
2   6666 3333
3   9701 245 931
4   9701 245 932
5   2666 8888
6   4822 8899
7   8822 9933
```

Comment: You want to split it into certain groups of numbers?  Your numbers are split differently into different groups, how are you determining which one to split twice only and which one to split 3 times?  By the length of the full string?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: if phone number is 10 digits it will split into every  3 digits with space and if it is 8 digits split into every 4 digits with space.

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done? In what manner of writing does "9701" look like three digits?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a query like below
<kbd>**[See working demo](http://rextester.com/VBNLD98150)**</kbd>

```
select id,
phone=case 
    when 
        len(phone)=10 
    then
        FORMAT(cast(phone as bigint), '### ### ###')  
     when 
        len(phone)=8 
    then
        FORMAT(cast(phone as bigint), '#### ####') 
end
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use case and build the string or format as others have suggested.

```
SELECT
  id
 ,CASE 
    WHEN LEN(phone) = 10 THEN SUBSTRING(phone, 1, 4) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(phone, 5, 3) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(phone, 8, 3)
    WHEN LEN(phone) = 8 THEN LEFT(phone, 4) + ' ' + RIGHT(phone, 4)
  END
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [`format()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
select format(PHONE, '### ### ###') as Phone
from table t;
```

`Edit` : You can use case expression for *conditional* formatting

```
select *, (case when len(Phone) = 8
                 then format(Phone, '#### ####')
                 else format(Phone, '#### ### ###')
            end) as Phone
from table t;
```